# No me reconoce la variable de conexión a Base de datos

Tags: php

Tengo esta funcion en **PHP**

```
function Productos(){
    require_once("conexion.php");
    $data = file_get_contents("productos.json");
    $producto = json_decode($data, true);
    foreach($producto as $a){
        $consulta = $conn->prepare("Insert into productos values(?,?,?)");
        $consulta->bindParam(1,$a["codigo"]);
        $consulta->bindParam(2,$a["Nombre"]);
        $consulta->bindParam(3,$a["descripcion"]);
        $consulta->execute();
    }
}
```

Me pone que no me reconoce `$conn`. Mientras que si la saco de la función y la pongo en el archivo index directamente me funciona correctamente. Y la ruta está correcta ya que está en la misma carpeta que el archivo de funciones.

Comment: No vale con que este en la misma carpeta, debe estar en el mismo fuente **final**

Comment: pasale `$conn` a la función, quedandote de la siguiente forma : `function Productos($conn )`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias no había caido en ese detalle.

Comment: Es muy probable que el problema sea por el uso de `require_once`, ya que si `conexion.php` fue requerido anteriormente e intentas incluirlo de nuevo, dicha acción no se realizará.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que estás teniendo es sobre el ámbito de las variables, te recomiendo que le eches un vistazo a la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php) en la que podrás ver ejemplos y está bien explicado.

No te reconoce la variable `$conn` ya que dentro de la función se está utilizando una versión local de la variable, a la que no se le ha asignado ningún valor en su ámbito.

Para solventar esto tienes varias opciones:

**1.Suministrar la variable a la función**, como ya te he mencionado en el comentario, puedes modificar tu función para  pasarle la variable, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
function Productos($conn){
     //tu código
}
```

**2.Utilizar la palabra clave global**, todas las referencias a las variables que utilicen esta palabra clave se referirán a la versión global de la variable.

```
function Productos(){
     global $conn;
     //tu código
}
```

**3.Uso de $GLOBALS en lugar de global**, El array $GLOBALS es un array asociativo con el nombre de la variable global como clave y los contenidos de dicha variable como el valor del elemento del array. $GLOBALS existe en cualquier ámbito.

```
function Productos(){
     //tu código
     $consulta = $GLOBALS['conn']->prepare("Insert into productos values(?,?,?)");

}
```

Comment: perfecto muchas gracias :)

Comment: Aunque el problema se haya resuelto, es recomendable usar un modelo orientado a objetos para tu conexión a la bd. Eso significa que puedes tener una clase llamada por ejemplo `Db` la cual instancias cada vez que vayas a usar conexiones: `$db=new Db();` y luego haces todas las operaciones llamando a métodos de tu clase `Db` mediante la variable `$db`... Me extraña que recomiendes el uso de globales para estos casos y no menciones una posibilidad mejor basada en POO. Ver un ejemplo de clase de conexión funcional aquí: **[PHP-PDO en Github](https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO)**